# Count number of rows in flexbox

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-flexboxlayout

In my android application i have used `flexbox-layout`.
I am adding buttons dynamically into the `flexbox`.
I need to know how many rows are currently rendered (How many rows flexbox created to show the buttons)
This is my `flexbox-layout`:

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/filterActivity_tags_container"
    app:flexWrap="wrap"
    app:justifyContent="flex_end" />
```

Answer (score 3):

i have find the solution guys!

```
mFlexbox.getFlexLines().size()
```

Comment: same not returning number of rows when using FlexboxLayoutManger as layoutManager for RecyclerView.

Comment: Not suggest this because this is give wrong result , I have try this lot of time when you remove all view then size return same as previous and this size is update when child view finish drawing -  Don't use this   API

Comment: @sushantgosavi layoutManager.getFlexLines().size()

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Answer No **You need to create your custom FlexboxLayout to get row count**

There is some API such as

> mFlexbox.getFlexLines().size()
>
> mFlexbox.getFlexLinesInternal().size()

But this is give you wrong result because this play with data not view suppose you call removeAllView()  still it give you same result because it does not update list after remove data, One another thing I have notice that it update line count after one child view already  added to flexbox row .

This is my observation while implementing this this may be wrong on some case